# Send RAW IR code with ATtiny85

Tags: attiny85

I am looking for a ATtiny85 send RAW IR code using a ATtiny85.  I have it sending HEX code just fine, but just cannot find something for RAW. I have IRsend RAW IR running just fine on a NANO. Problem is will not compile on a ATtiny85. ATtiny85 does not have Timer2, and it seems most of the code written uses Timer2. ATtiny has only Timer 0 and 1, both 8 bits wide. I tried to port it over from NANO to ATtiny85 by fooling with the IRLib2, but just do not have enough experience to make it happen..HELP
Thanks
Darryl..

Comment: what does this mean? `sending HEX code just fine`

Comment: The IRremote library for Arduino does support of using different timer, all you need is correctly configure it of the board you use. As far as I can see is that it does support [ATtiny85](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/boarddefs.h#L144), all you need is to configure it correctly. You can run [IRremoteInfo](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/IRremoteInfo/IRremoteInfo.ino) example sketch to confirm if you have the correct setup.

Comment: The definition of the timer to be used and how to generate the 38kHz clock for each MCU type is defined in [boarddefs.cpp](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/boarddefs.h)

Comment: When i say HEX, one of the IR Libs uses HEX instead of RAW  Example = 0x1CE318E7 (SANYO Mute .  Raw is a series of numbers representing Carrier on time and carrier off time